Couchbase Node SDK causing error when transpiling and bundling TS code to JS
Basically the issue relies on the step that I run the following command to transpile+bundle my TS code to JS:
esbuild --tsconfig=./tsconfig.build.json --bundle --platform=node --outfile=dist/index.js ./src/index.ts
I have couchbase ^4.4.0 as a dependency of my project, and EVERY time I run the project after bundled, it shows this error:
/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:23778
    CN_ROOT = path.resolve(path.dirname(__filename), "..");
            ^

ReferenceError: CN_ROOT is not defined
    at node_modules/couchbase/scripts/prebuilds.js (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:23778:13)
    at __require (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:9:50)
    at node_modules/couchbase/dist/binding.js (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:24295:7)
    at __require (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:9:50)
    at node_modules/couchbase/dist/couchbase.js (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:37632:37)
    at __require (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:9:50)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joaocasarin/Desktop/job/server-code/refactoring/dist/index.js:42232:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)

Node.js v20.11.0

It doesn't happen if I just transpile the TS code to JS, but due to internal decisions, we want it bundled as well, and esbuild seemed to be the fastest option so far.
What can we do to resolve this?
EDIT:
These two are the ONLY mentions of CN_ROOT in the bundled code:


Disclaimer: I’m the maintainer of Cbjs.
Unfortunately, the only solution I can give you is to use Cbjs, instead of the official package.
It’s a Couchbase SDK for Node.js compatible with the official one, focused on a great TypeScript experience and a good DX in general.
It is written on top of the official SDK with some runtime additions, but radically enhanced types.
To achieve that, some parts of the code have be rewritten, including the way the binaries are loaded, which is where your bundle struggles.
